# Force Minecraft-pi to use PiTFT, not HDMI

Tags: display, pitft, minecraft

My daughter just got the [PiTFT](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1601) for her Raspberry Pi, and I finally picked up myself a Pi(B+, woo woo)+touchscreen as well.

Given that she's in second grade and I think every other kid in school plays Minecraft, she was extremely excited when she realized it was preloaded on her Pi.

However, when she launches it the main minecraft window (with the decorations) shows up on the TFT nice and black. But the actual minecraft display shows up out of the HDMI. We've tried `export FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1` a la the [Adafruit guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/software-installation) in console and then running `minecraft-pi` but alas! No luck. The minecraft game window still goes the wrong direction.

So, how can we make Minecraft show up on the PiTFT?

Comment: I tweaked your title a bit in hopes this would get you the attention you need.

Comment: It is a good question to post on adafruit forum as well.

Comment: @WayneWerner Also I would not allow a young one to squint on a small LCD for hour or so.

Comment: What do you mean by 'out of the HDMI'? Do you mean out of the screen, or off of the tab? The latter is normal, but if it is out of the screen, there is a problem. I can look into it if it is out of the screen and try to solve it.

Comment: It displays on the wrong(?) framebuffer - I have X running on `/dev/fb1` and the Minecraft window decorations show up there (the PiTFT), but the actual minecraft SDL(?) window shows up on `/dev/fb0` (HDMI display).

Comment: I have found the same hole. Despite of a few operations, for the moment, i am searching how to go around it (with a workaround **if possible**).
I will post soon an update for this post.
Pr.K

Comment: Have you looked into \ used fbcp?

Comment: I've tried it, and it kinda works - but it really thrashes the CPU. When running Minecraft alone the CPU can even idle - but with fbcp it's always at 100% :(

Answer (score 4):

If Minecraft on the pi uses OpenGL, this won't work because OGL will not work on the PiTFT.  Adafruit has an [explanation of this](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=57557).

Examining the `minecraft-pi` binary downloaded [from here](http://pi.minecraft.net/?page_id=10) reveals that it does link to the openGL-ES libs on the pi, so you will not be able to use it on the PiTFT.